# Change default stylus pointer style in android

Tags: android, android-layout, stylus-pen

It is possible to capture different stylus events on Android 4.0 and above.

But there does not seem to be a way to change the pointer style to something other than the default, since **I want to set a small image dynamically as pointer when the stylus hover event occurs**.

I went through the Android motion event API documentation, but I did not find any information about this.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Which device are you using? Have you looked at the manufacturer APIs?

Comment: I want to have general solution. Should work for any android device which supports hover event using stylus. For Manufacturer APIs, samsung galaxy tab 10.1 I tried SPend SDK APIs (Available at Samsung Developer site), But couldn't get any way to customize for galaxy tab to add new pointer style.

Comment: thanks guys I got the answer. Will post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for Samsung devices.

After digging into [SPen SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk) sources, I found that it is very easy to change hover icon.

You need to use this function:

```
public boolean setSPenCustomHoverIcon(Context paramContext, View paramView, Drawable paramDrawable);
```

You just need to pass: application `context`, `View` and `Drawable` Icon.